# Color blindness: Are you aware of it? Do you design for it?

Tags: colors, accessibility, color-blindness

I'm curious whether many of us who do design or take design decisions have ever heard of this problem.

I'm aware there are dangerous color combinations, like green + red. This is probably one of the most popular cases of color blindness. If you have green text on a red background and vice versa some people won't see anything.

I've also seen in practice that green text on a blue background was not seen by one guy.

What other color compositions should be avoided, and how often these cases are to be expected?

Let us make some ranging by encounter probability who has the numbers.

Addition: I've just remembered one very bad example that causes problems to just about everyone - blue text on a black background. It's unreadable for all intents and purposes. Never could understand what could possibly compel a web master to use this color combination...

Comment: I find your use of the word "popular" amusing in this context. :)

Comment: At my last company, our CEO was red+green color blind so we planned for this constantly -- if for no other reason than to keep from pissing him off.

Comment: Blue on black doesn't seem unreadable to me. I've tried different shades. Only the very dark shaded become unreadable because of the lack of contrast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it must be pretty common, and developers who do not take it into account are doomed to lock out a surprisingly high proportion of their customers. In my workplace, out of around 30 people in the R&D department, 2 are colour blind to some degree, and one is of restricted vision - he needs to use the windows "High Contrast" colour scheme to get any work done. A good test is to run your app in the various high contrast schemes. If you haven't done it I can pretty much guarantee it will be unreadable. You need to be able to handle schemes like this for better accessibility.

Comment: Iraimbilanja, there are more colour-deficient folks around than you realise.

Comment: 10% was surprisingly high to me. Maybe it isn't to you? Do you know more?

Comment: 2 out of 30 is 6% and this truly is not worth the worry when you can instead double your users by designing an attractive application

Comment: That's nice. Would you omit having disabled carparks in shopping malls too? How about banning guide dogs from restaurants as well? After all there aren't that many blind people around that we need to care what they think huh

Comment: I'm partially colorblind. Found out in second grade, colored the Atlantic Ocean purple :X. "What? No that's blue!". I really appreciate it when games especially add a "colorblind mode" that adds symbols in addition to the colors. Detracts nothing from gameplay or style, in some cases it actually looks nicer. I've found I have the opposite problem! Studies have shown that people, such as myself, are never fooled by things like Camouflage (Now I know why I thought it was so silly), because the patterns simply don't work on us.

Comment: When I design things, I tend to stay away from colors as I mess them up more often than not. Not so much in the design category, moreso in usability. I'm almost never using enough contrast, because the way I see the colors is more contrasting than normal people would. I always take the time to have a few people look things over. Usually my dad and a few web design pals. My dad isn't colorblind, just old and fast to complain about bad color choices. (50!)

Answer (score 16):

I allways test my pages in http://www.vischeck.com/vischeck/vischeckURL.php to make sure I havent chosen really bad colors. Or this one http://colorfilter.wickline.org/

Comment: Wow, I thought color blindness was much more severe than what it actually is.  You would think all the green/red on stackoverflow would cause issues but dealing with muted green and orange isn't that big of a deal.

Answer (score 7):

I'm color blind myself, of the green-red type, so yes, I take this into account :)

Do follow the design guidelines mentioned in the websites others have linked to. But there are some ideas I'd like to stress:

- Hardcoding *any* colours may not be a great idea. Configurable and skinnable are good.
- In particular, hardcoding indicators to "the red one = bad, the green one = good", may not be a good idea.
- And, hardcoding the *same* indicator to "when it's green it's good, when it's red it's bad" IS definitely a bad idea.

(Is the battery charged?)

Answer (score 3):

My direct boss is colorblind, so yes we take this into account. ;-).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, definitely need to consider it in any case where you are using colours to identify and/or demark things.

Classic case is traffic light style indicators which are generally red, yellow and green.  Red/Green colour-blindness is quite common.  If you are creating apps that need to comply with accessibility legislation you have to take this, and a host of other things, into consideration.

The government of Quebec in Canada recognise this to the extent that their actual traffic lights are different shapes as well as different colours.  Makes sense really.

Comment: I saw some design suggesting that we make traffic lights cooler with square lights instead of round - and enhance the turn-signals to only use one arrow that would shine red or green.. that amused me ^^

Answer (score 3):

Websites should cater for everyone, whether they're colour blind, deaf or whatever.

The Royal Institute for the Blind in the UK has some interesting articles on web designing for partially sited people;
[link text](http://www.rnib.org.uk/xpedio/groups/public/documents/code/public_rnib008789.hcsp)

Including colour-contrast [link text](http://www.rnib.org.uk/xpedio/groups/public/documents/PublicWebsite/public_contrast.hcsp)

and the use of colour to convey information [link text](http://www.rnib.org.uk/xpedio/groups/public/documents/PublicWebsite/public_colouralone.hcsp)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows you can query the system for the System Colors. I allways use them.

You can test your app, using high contrast screen settings, if all is readable I suppose it's ok.

The article that opened my eyes to this is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb263953.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've done some work for US gov departments who are bound by section 508, so it does come up.

Red/Green is by far the most common form, but others exist (notably blue/yellow and monochromatic) so in general the important thing is to maintain high levels of contrast.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from green + red, another relatively common type of color blindness is blue and yellow.

We take color blindness into consideration when creating our games. One game we designed (Arcade Lines) features colored balls you have to align in same-colored rows. We tried to account for color blindness by offering a special skin for color-blind people which not only has different colors, but also different shapes (one shape for each color).

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you [this](http://colorschemedesigner.com/) website. It has a colors scheme selector and in the bottom right part of it there is a drop down menu used to switch between common eye related problems and changing scheme accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've never though of this. However thinking back now I can't remember any cases where my applications would have depended on color either. Text is nearly always white or black (though red or green are sometimes used), and background colors are pretty pale, mostly just for some eye-candy, not information. I'll keep this in mind now though. It's not that hard do get a webpage to be kinda-high-contrast. :)

Comment: It's surprisingly hard to mess up, you may think it's common sense, but some people just don't know better.

Answer (score 0):

Red-green may be the most common, but not the only type of colour deficiency.

In general, your user interface should still be visible and usable when viewed as grayscale or sepia tones. Text and backgrounds must have a high level of contrast to allow distinguishable shapes purely by tones and not colour.

Visual elements that involve colour and not unique art/icons can be accompanied by text to give more detail descriptions on what they represent.

Answer (score 0):

Color Oracle is a great tool that simulates different types of color blindness.  You can run your app/website, and run this app -- it will give you a good idea of how color blind users will interpret your creation.

http://colororacle.cartography.ch/

Answer (score 0):

I found out this the hard way when I told my colleague to press the red button.. when he said "which one?" I thought he was just being dim, so I told him again.. then he told me he was colour blind and I was the one feeling stupid.

He works for the railways now, writing signalling software. Good job the red light is always the one on top :)

So do you have to take colour blindness into account? Possibly not, just like you don't design your screens for large font support too, but you should if you want to do a truly good job instead of a mostly acceptable one.

Answer (score 0):

I once wrote an in-house application that featured a scatterplot with different series distinguished by color.  My primary user turned out to be color-blind (red-green, I think), so I supplemented the color with variation in symbols.